# Let $G$ be a group and $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$. Let $a,b\in G$. Show that either $Ha\cap Kb=\phi$ or $Ha\cap Kb =(H\cap K)c$ for some $c\in G$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$. Let $a,b\in G$. Show that either $Ha\cap Kb=\phi$ or $Ha\cap Kb =(H\cap K)c$ for some $c\in G$.

We know that, for $a\in G$, then $Ha\cap Ka =(H\cap K)a$.Now, $Ha$ and $Kb$ are two right cosets . If $h\in Ha\cap Kb$, then $h\in Ha$ and $h\in Kb$. But I don't quite know how to proceed from here . I am not quite getting it.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $Ha\cap Kb \neq \emptyset $ and let $x\in Ha\cap Kb  $, then I claim that  $$Ha \cap Kb=(H\cap K)x$$ Indeed let $y\in Ha\cap Kb$, then $yx^{-1}=f \in H\cap K$. So $$y=fx \in (H\cap K)x. $$
The reverse inclusion is trivial.

Comment: How did u know that $y\in Ha\cap Kb$? Also, how is $yx^{-1}\in H\cap K$?...I am not quite getting it....

Comment: @Franklin In order to prove equality, I started by proving the inclusion of the LHS in the RHS,that is why I supposed  that $y\in Ha\cap Kb$,concerning the  second question $y\in Ha \leftrightarrow Ha=Hy$, since $Ha=Hx$, we deduce that $Hy=Hx \leftrightarrow yx^{-1}\in H$, by the same reasoning $yx^{-1}\in K$, so $yx^{-1}\in H\cap K$ which means that $y \in H\cap K x$

Comment: Thanks a lot! But still how are u proving the reverse inclusion ? I am still not quite getting it...